# why is springboot not picking up apache kafka bootstrap-servers in application.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My Springboot application does not seem to pick up the credentials provided in the application.yml for confluent kafka credentials. It is able to pick for other credentials like email apart from Kafka confluent which makes me realise that the issue is coming from my configuration. I pasted what was made available to me on their platform.

I have tried to comment out the credentials, I noticed the application gives the same issues. Here is my configuration.

```yaml
  kafka:
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          enabled: true
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='<redacted>' password='<redacted>';
      bootstrap-servers: pkc-12p03.xxxxxx.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
      session:
        timeout:
          ms: 5000
      basic:
        auth:
          credentials:
            source: USER_INFO
          user:
            info: <redacted>:<redacted>
      schema:
        registry:
          url: https://pkc-12p03.xxxx.azure.confluent.cloud:443
```

This is what I get in response when I try to hit the endpoint

```
2023-07-26 15:43:10 [,] - INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-07-26 15:43:10 [,] - WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-07-26 15:43:10 [,] - WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-07-26 15:43:11 [,] - INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-07-26 15:43:11 [,] - WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-07-26 15:43:11 [,] - WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-07-26 15:43:12 [,] - INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-07-26 15:43:12 [,] - WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-07-26 15:43:12 [,] - WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

It times out. This is how I am using Kafka. It is a simple usage.

```java
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    private final MailConfiguration mailConfiguration;
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, MailRequestDto> kafkaTemplate;
    private final String topicName = "email_topic";

    @Override
    public BaseResponse<?> sendMail( MailRequestDto emailRequestDto) {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

       try {
           mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(mailConfiguration.getMailUsername());
           mimeMessageHelper.setTo(emailRequestDto.getRecipient());
           mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(emailRequestDto.getSubject());
           mimeMessageHelper.setText(emailRequestDto.getText());
           javaMailSender.send(message);

           kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, emailRequestDto);

           Map<String, Object> responseData = buildResponseData(emailRequestDto);
           return buildSuccessResponse(responseData);
       } catch (MessagingException e) {
           return buildErrorResponse(e.getLocalizedMessage());
       }
    }

}
```

Doing a telnet on my bootstrap-server, I get success message. What could be wrong please? I have the necessary dependencies in my pom.xml

Comment: You should probably change your credentials now that you have shared them here.

Comment: Thanks but to start with, these are not my actual credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please learn how to use SO markdown to format code (see my edits).

You need `spring:` as the first element.

`bootstrap-servers` should NOT be under `properties`, just under `spring.kafka`.

`properties` is for kafka properties that are not exposed directly by Boot.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Otherwise, Spring Boot will default to `127.0.0.1:9092`

Comment: spring is my first element. I have other elements other than that of confluent kafka. I fixed it earlier by writing a config for both producers and consumers. I will go through the docs now. Thanks a lot